# Create and control start up scripts in BusyBox

Tags: linux, startup, busybox, init.d, runlevel

I have compiled a custom linux kernel in BusyBox. BusyBox `init` does not support runlevels. When the kernel boots up in BusyBox, it first executes `init` which looks for the specified runlevel in `/etc/inittab`. BusyBox `init` works just fine without `/etc/inittab`. When no `inittab` is found it has the following behavior:

```
::sysinit:/etc/init.d/rcS
```

This part is very clear to me, but I would like to know how to manage daemons that start up networking, create serial ports, or start `java` processes. I have looked in the scripts that reside in `/etc/init.d/` but I don't understand how to manage them. I am looking for a good tutorial or solution to control these services myself without an automated tool like `buildroot`. I want to understand how these scripts work and how to create devices in `/dev/` (right now I only have `console` and `ttyAM0`).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For buildroot all your scripts must be placed in `$path_to_buildroot/output/target/etc/init.d` before build image.
In my case this directory contains `rcS` and few scripts named S[0-99]script_name. So you can create your own start\stop script.

rcS:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Start all init scripts in /etc/init.d
# executing them in numerical order.
#
for i in /etc/init.d/S??* ;do

     # Ignore dangling symlinks (if any).
     [ ! -f "$i" ] && continue

     case "$i" in
    *.sh)
        # Source shell script for speed.
        (
        trap - INT QUIT TSTP
        set start
        . $i
        )
        ;;
    *)
        # No sh extension, so fork subprocess.
        $i start
        ;;
    esac
done
```

and for example S40network:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Start the network....
#

case "$1" in
  start)
    echo "Starting network..."
    /sbin/ifup -a
    ;;
  stop)
    echo -n "Stopping network..."
    /sbin/ifdown -a
    ;;
  restart|reload)
    "$0" stop
    "$0" start
    ;;
  *)
    echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
    exit 1
esac

exit $?
```

Comment: `S[0-99]script_name` filename syntax will run `S10*` before `S2*` and break the script.

Comment: @Tim not necessarily "break the script", just zero-pad. Sure `S20*` runs after `S10*`, if you want something to come before `S10` you need to call it `S01*`, `S02*`, etc. NBD.

Answer (score 8):

It's bad idea to change your fs in "target" folder. This is because changes in `output/target/` do not survive the `make clean` command.

In buildroot manual decribed how to  [do it correctly](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#rootfs-custom)

You should create dir somewhere which partly overlay file system. 
For example you can create dir "your-overlay" in buildroot dir where you create this struct

`your-overlay/etc/init.d/<any_file>`

Then you should set path to this overlay in defconfig

`System configuration > Root filesystem overlay directories`

(or, find BR2_ROOTFS_OVERLAY)

*Also, the recommended path for this overlay is* 
`board/<company>/<boardname>/rootfs-overlay`

Comment: Sample setup when using Buildroot as a submodule: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/4768027b9e73511043c1db8771ab773502c44c09/buildroot_config_fragment#L7

Comment: OP is using only BusyBox and indicates he wants to achieve his goal without buildroot. I don't see this answer relevant to the question. It's more a comment to the accepted answer.