# How to find out in which order /etc/init.d scripts are load on Debian?

Tags: debian, startup, init, sysvinit

I want to run one sysvinit script before another and figured out how to do that.

To make sure, this actually happens in the the order I like, I would like to see a list, in which order that happens.

I found `sudo insserv --showall` already, but can't make head or tail of it, since it lists init scripts multiple times.

How to find out in which order /etc/init.d scripts are load on Debian?

Comment: BusyBox users arriving at this post: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59018/create-and-control-start-up-scripts-in-busybox Note the comment "executing them in numerical order"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's some files in /etc/init.d/ directory:

```
$ ls -al /etc/init.d/ | grep -i depend
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2739 Feb 17 05:20 .depend.boot
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2221 Feb 17 05:20 .depend.start
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1855 Feb 17 05:20 .depend.stop
```

Whenever you run `update-rc.d` the files will change. `.depend.boot` file is for `S` level,  `.depend.start` is for `2 3 4 5` levels and `.depend.stop` for `0 1 6`.

In my case, I have the following order in `.depend.start`:

```
TARGETS = killprocs motd nvidia-kernel nfs-common rsyslog privoxy virtualbox
linuxlogo acpi-fakekey binfmt-support fancontrol openvpn hddtemp cgconfig 
dropbox-container dbus dnscrypt-proxy pulseaudio atd cryptmount exim4 
qbittorrent-nox ddclient acpi-support smartmontools ssh ntp loadcpufreq acpid 
cron rsync cgrulesengd cpufrequtils bootlogs bootchart-done single rmnologin 
rc.local stop-bootlogd
```

You can also see why the order presents in the way you see above. Each next line looks like this:

```
cgrulesengd: rsyslog cgconfig
```

which means that `cgrulesengd` needs `rsyslog` `cgconfig` to be started prior.

Answer (score 7):

For every runlevel (0 6) there is an folder /etc/rc[N].d

In every directory there are symbolic link either starts with an "S" or with a “K”. "S" to start e "K" to stop. The scripts are executed **in a lexical sort manner of the filename**, in other words S10script will be executed first than S20myscript. For example :

we have two simple scripts, the second.sh script must be execute after the fist.sh script in the current runlevel.

```
    root@localhost init.d]# cat /etc/init.d/first.sh 
    #!/bin/bash
    #
    echo 'I am the first'  >> /var/log/messages

    root@localhost init.d]# cat /etc/init.d/second.sh   
    #!/bin/bash
    #
    echo 'I am the second'  >> /var/log/messages
```

What is my current level?

```
    [root@localhost init.d]# runlevel 
    N 5
```

Now we need a symbolic link starting namely S(N)myScript for the first and S(N+1)mysecondScript:

```
    root@localhost rc5.d]# ln -s /etc/init.d/first.sh /etc/rc5.d/S1first
    root@localhost rc5.d]# ln -s /etc/init.d/second.sh /etc/rc5.d/S2second
```

We can reboot and  check the messages log:

```
    [root@localhost ~]# cat /var/log/messages | grep "I am" -A 1 -B 1
    Dec 13 13:53:36 localhost rpc.statd[3468]: Version 1.0.9 Starting
    I am the first
    Dec 13 13:53:37 localhost hcid[3532]: Bluetooth HCI daemon
    --
    Dec 13 13:53:40 localhost automount[3689]: lookup_read_master:       lookup(nisplus): couldn't locate nis+ table auto.master
    I am the second
    Dec 13 13:53:41 localhost gpm[3785]: *** info [startup.c(95)]:
```

Tested on old Centos5

Comment: I recommend using /usr/bin/logger to append to the system log instead of redirection, so you don't accidentally write ">" by accident one day and wipe out your logs.