# Unblocking wifi using rfkill on startup

Tags: debian, init.d

I'm using Debian wheezy on an embedded platform (iMX.6 on Solidrun Hummingboard), and I have rfkill blocking my WiFi.

the command `sudo rfkill unblock wifi` works, so I've created a script called `unblock_wifi.sh` and put it in `/etc/init.d`:

```
#!/bin/bash

logFile=/var/log/unblock_wifi.log
timestamp=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)

echo "unblock_wifi - Started at $timestamp" > $logFile
rfkill unblock wifi &>> $logFile

timestamp=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)
echo  "unblock_wifi - Done at $timestamp" >> $logFile
```

On boot, the script is called (the log appears on /var/log and the times are correct. There is nothing but the start and stop messages) but the wifi is still blocked. If I call the script myself after boot, the wifi is enabled.

My script is on `/etc/rc2.d/S05unblock_wifi.sh`, and it appears last on `ls`, I *think* it means that it runs last. 
There's no script for rfkill though...

How does rfkill run without having a script in init.d? It probably runs after my script has ran. Where should I put my script in order for it to run after rfkill?

EDIT: I've searched all around for an answer, but everybody seems to recommend putting a script in `/etc/init.d`, which is what I tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Timidger's comment I've set out to get a deeper understanding of the boot sequence and also found out the connman was the culprit disabling the wifi. Disabling its service did what I needed.

For future reference: The boot order is decided by the dependencies needed by each service. If you want your script to run after something - Require it as a dependency (See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115495/how-to-find-out-in-which-order-etc-init-d-scripts-are-load-on-debian))
 -

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it's in the right order? [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115495/how-to-find-out-in-which-order-etc-init-d-scripts-are-load-on-debian)  question seems to say `ls` doesn't show the right ordering, so you might want to make sure it's loaded at the end of the other services.

Answer (score 0):

On systemd based systems rfkill status is controlled via the `systemd-rfkill` service, so this should perform the functionality of loading and saving across reboots.