# Understanding the linux boot order in /etc/init.d

Tags: debian, init.d, sysvinit

This question is about Debian, but I guess it's the same in many linux environments.

The `/etc/init.d` directory defines the services that run at boot-time. As I see it, there are two mechanisms that define who runs and when:

- runlevel directories - The `/etc/rcN.d/` directories, in which there are symlinks to scripts in `init.d` with numbers that define the running order. These symlinks are generated from running `update-rc.d`.
- insserv files - `.depend.start/stop/boot` files that are generated from the utility `insserv`. In these files you see the running scripts under `TARGETS`, and the order in which they appear is the running order (See [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115495/how-to-find-out-in-which-order-etc-init-d-scripts-are-load-on-debian?lq=1))

So first question - Which of these decides the boot order?

---

In order to change the boot order I guess you can either edit the symlinks name in the `rc.N` directories, or change the order of appearence in `.depend.start`. But both of these changes will be overwritten by a call to `insserv` or `update-rc.d`.

So second question - How do you control the boot order init.d scripts in a way that will last after a call to `insserv` or `update-rc.d`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `sysvinit` (systemd is different, but you'd use units there, not initscripts), the boot order is determined during boot by the ordering of files in `/etc/rc?.d`. The symlinks there are generated by `update-rc.d` with the help of `insserv`, which is really an implementation detail (as are the `.depend.boot` etc. files). All you need to care about are the dependencies between initscripts, declared in their LSB headers; *e.g.*:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          unbound
# Required-Start:    $network $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $network $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
### END INIT INFO
```

If you want to change the boot order, you need to add dependencies to the relevant initscripts. The safest way to do that is to add overrides to `/etc/insserv/overrides`: create a new file there with the same name as the script you wish to override, and write the new header to that file. Then run `update-rc.d yourscript defaults` to re-calculate the symlinks.

You'll find more information in the manpages for [`insserv`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=insserv&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%208%20jessie&format=html&locale=en) and [`update-rc.d`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=update-rc.d&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%208%20jessie&format=html&locale=en).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does update-rc.d uses insserv when deciding the boot order?

Comment: Yes, `update-rc.d` uses `insserv`to determine the boot order.